# How to add datas to chart js from javascript array itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, charts, chart.js

I would like to use [chart js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/) in there at data structure data, if i give number as

`data : [40,80,5,190,56,55,40]` working fine. If i give a array variable or string variable which holds that number like

```
 var myvalues = my_array.toString(); 
   alert(myvalues);
```

am getting 5,10,14,18 for the variable as well as for array. Now when i use the array or string with the chart data  i can't able to get the chart if i try like the below

```
data : [myvalues]
```

with full code for barChartData

```
var barChartData = {
            labels: [description],
            datasets: [
                {
                    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    scaleOverride: true,
                    scaleSteps: 100,
                    stepValue: 1,
                    barShowStroke: false,
                    data: [myvalues]
                },
                {
                    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    scaleOverride: true,
                    scaleSteps: 100,
                    barShowStroke: false,
                    stepValue: 1,
                    data: [myvalues]
                }
            ]

        }
```

Here `description` is the another variable holding information about the label this too not working.

How to assign data and labels from javascript array or string to the chart js?

Answer (score 9):

You have to create the `Array`'s, populate them, and only type the array name inside object without needing to surround it with `[` and `]`

**Example:**

```
var description = new Array();
description.push('a');
description.push('b');
var myvalues = new Array();
myvalues.push('c');
myvalues.push('d');
var barChartData = {
            labels: description,
            datasets: [
                {
                    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.5)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    scaleOverride: true,
                    scaleSteps: 100,
                    stepValue: 1,
                    barShowStroke: false,
                    data: myvalues
                },
                {
                    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                    scaleOverride: true,
                    scaleSteps: 100,
                    barShowStroke: false,
                    stepValue: 1,
                    data: myvalues
                }
            ]

        }
```