# Passing Array to Chart.js not working, chart not rendering

Tags: javascript, typescript, charts, chart.js, chart.js2

I am trying to display a chart by passing in arrays of data to Chart.js. If I pass arrays, the chart does not render at all; it's as if the arrays are all empty. If I hard code the values into the location where the arrays are, the chart renders fine.
I'm new to JavaScript/TypeScript...
I found these similar questions, but they don't seem to work in my situation:

[Array not working correctly in Chartjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40278334/array-not-working-correctly-in-chartjs)

[How to add datas to chart js from javascript array itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20266849/how-to-add-datas-to-chart-js-from-javascript-array-itself)

Here is my code. The chart does not render if I remove the hard coded arrays and un-comment the array variables.

```
  buildChart() {
var momentArr = new Array(); var weightArr = new Array(); var bmiArr = new Array();
this.weightList.forEach(elements => {
  elements.forEach(element => {
    momentArr.push(element.moment);
    weightArr.push(element.weight);
    bmiArr.push(element.bmi);
  });
})

console.log(momentArr);
console.log(weightArr);
console.log(bmiArr);

this.weightChart = new Chart(this.weightCanvas.nativeElement, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [1500948156623,1500948161541], //momentArr,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'Weight',
        borderColor: "#3cba9f",
        fill: false,
        data: [300, 280] //weightArr
      },
      {
        label: 'BMI',
        borderColor: "#8e5ea2",
        fill: false,
        data: [150, 140] //bmiArr
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          displayFormats: {
            quarter: 'MMM YYYY'
          }
        }
      }],
      yAxes: [{
        type: 'linear',
        ticks: { beginAtZero: false}
      }]
    }
  }

});
}
```

FYI, weightList is a FirebaseListObservable.

Comment: What does the output of you `console.log` statements look like? Is there a chance that the data in `weightList` is strings and not numbers?

Comment: All three arrays are numbers (same numbers as in the code. I tried screen shotting the console output, but was unable to.) All three arrays have length 2, and in console print out as: [ ] , expanded, : num 1, num2

Comment: I double checked the output of the log, and they are all numbers, and the variable is an Array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the issue wasn't chart.js at all; it was the asynchronous nature of data retrieval from Firebase. I added a ref.on(....) and populate the arrays as mentioned in the answer by @john townsend, and it is rendering correctly now.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You will want to do

```
this.weightChart.data.datasets[0].data.concat(weightArr);

this.weightChart.update();
```

And so on for the other datasets. If the concat isn't working, you'll want to loop through weightArr and push to the chart, then update.

```
for (var i = 0 ; i < weightArr.length; i++){
            this.weightChart.data.datasets[0].data.push(weightArr[i]);
}

this.weightChart.update();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - will try it out tonight. Still, I don't understand why the arrays of data have to be 'loaded' after creating the Chart and then re-updated?

Comment: So in the version I am using (I believe it is 2.6.X) the initial create does not require you to call chart.update(). Later on though you are required to call chart.update() if you change the the chart JSON object. I think it is because chartjs uses the canvas and must redraw the entire canvas on each update.

Comment: I tried both of your suggestions, and still the chart does not have any data. I am really at a loss as to why this wouldn't work...any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I found the Chart.JS docs for updates, but it is exactly what you suggested, and what I did - http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html